# Extracting IP address and ports of NMAP scan in seperate lines

Tags: awk, sed, nmap

I do a nmap scan of a domain and want to output the IP address and all open ports in the form of:

```
127.0.0.1:22
127.0.0.1:80
127.0.0.1:443
```

I have the following bash script

```
nmap -vv -sV subdomain.domain.tld -oG - |  awk '/open/' | awk '{printf "%s:", $2;
  for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) {
    split($i,a,"/");
    if (a[2]=="open") printf ",%s",a[1];}
  print ""}' |
sed -e 's/,//'
```

It outputs the following:

```
127.0.0.1:22,80,443
```

I can't get it to pass the value of the IP address into the for loop so I can output it per line. I feel like it just needs a little tweak to get the output I want.

Comment: In your question you showed us the output you don't want and the output you do want but you never showed us the input to your awk script(s), i.e. the output of `nmap -vv -sV subdomain.domain.tld -oG -`, so there's only so much we can do to help you fix your script that parses the input. For all questions make sure to provide sample input AND output so we can best help you and have an example we can copy/paste to test with. Not my down vote or close vote btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the value of `$2`, which you can use printing the value of the ip with `:` and the port.

I think you can omit the pipe to `sed` at the end, and you can use a single pipe to `awk` starting with matching the pattern `/open/ {`

```
nmap -vv -sV localhost -oG - | awk -v OFS=':' '
/open/ {
  for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) {
    split($i,a,"/");
    if (a[2]=="open") print $2, a[1]
  }
}'
```

Output

```
127.0.0.1:80
127.0.0.1:443
...etc
```